# Define query result as variable for IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f8ce92b85e0f88c33df504b74e26fb40)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    event_date DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    sales_quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, product, sales_quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-23", "P001", "200"),
("2020-01-24", "P002", "400"),
("2020-01-25", "P003", "300"),
("2020-01-26", "P004", "900"),
("2020-01-27", "P005", "700"),
("2020-01-28", "P006", "100");
```

---

I am using a `query` on the above table that consists of mutliple `WHERE ... IN ...` conditions. 
The `IN` condition is based on a query that filters certain products from the `table`. 
Currently, I have to enter this query for each `IN` statement within the query.

Therefore, I am wondering if it is possible to define the query of the `IN` statement as `variable` so it does not have to be entered each time separately.

---

I tried somehting like this but could not make it work:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT
            product
            FROM sales
            WHERE sales_quantity > 600)
            
SELECT
product,
sales_quantity
FROM 

  (SELECT
  product,
  sales_quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE product IN 
     (cte)) t1
      
WHERE product IN 
    (cte)
      
GROUP BY 1;
```

Do you have any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the correct syntax uses `select`:

```
WHERE product IN (SELECT product FROM cte)
```

Often such queries are better written using `JOIN` or window functions.  But that is not the question you are asking.  You might want to ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.